# Selection of random cells with unique ID group

Tags: sampling

I have multiple measurements taken from the same individuals. I need to select a random measurement from an individual and subtract it from a random measurement from a different individual.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    Bat     FA
1   1709    37.0        
2   1709    37.1        
3   1727    38.0        
4   1727    38.0        
5   1745    36.0        
6   1745    35.9
```

I am not sure how to select the second random measurement while ensuring the selected measurement does not come from the same individual as the first random measurement.

Comment: I could imagine two approaches: 1) select 2 individuals uniformly at random, and for each selected individual select a single measurement uniformly at random from all of their measurements; or 2) select a pair of measurements uniformly at random, limiting to measurement pairs from two different individuals. These will differ if some individuals have more measurements than others. Which are you seeking?

Comment: Some individuals have more measurements than others. I was approaching it from the second method but I'm not sure how to limit the pairs from different individuals.

Comment: I believe the issue being raised by @josliber concerns the fact that different sampling algorithms obtain their data with different probabilities. We're trying to get enough information from you about the intended probabilities so that the answer is what you need and doesn't unexpectedly produce incorrect results. If you sample each *individual* with equal probabilities, you get one method; if you sample each *measurement* with equal probabilities, you get a different method in which individuals with more measurements are more likely to be in the sample. Can you explain your objectives?

Comment: I see...
I am comparing inter-individual measurement variability to intra-individual measurement variability. So each individual would need to have an equal probability of being sampled.

Comment: The standard way to make that comparison is with an Analysis of Variance, so it's natural to wonder what about your application precludes that technique and how the sampling is intended to improve on or replace ANOVA?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches here. One possible approach would be to compute all possible pairs of measurements, limiting to those from different individuals:

```
pairs <- t(combn(nrow(dat), 2))
pairs <- pairs[dat$Bat[pairs[,1]] != dat$Bat[pairs[,2]],]
pairs
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]    1    3
#  [2,]    1    4
#  [3,]    1    5
#  [4,]    1    6
#  [5,]    2    3
#  [6,]    2    4
#  [7,]    2    5
#  [8,]    2    6
#  [9,]    3    5
# [10,]    3    6
# [11,]    4    5
# [12,]    4    6
```

So we see that in your example there are 12 pairs of row numbers that we could randomly sample from. So if you wanted to draw 5 samples, you could do something like:

```
set.seed(144)
selected.pairs <- sample(nrow(pairs), 5, replace=TRUE)
(samps <- pairs[selected.pairs,])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    5
# [2,]    4    5
# [3,]    2    6
# [4,]    1    3
# [5,]    4    5
```

From this, it would be easy to get the data for the first and second observation for each of the pairs you selected:

```
(obs1 <- dat[pairs[selected.pairs,1],])
#      Bat   FA
# 2   1709 37.1
# 4   1727 38.0
# 2.1 1709 37.1
# 1   1709 37.0
# 4.1 1727 38.0
(obs2 <- dat[pairs[selected.pairs,2],])
#      Bat   FA
# 5   1745 36.0
# 5.1 1745 36.0
# 6   1745 35.9
# 3   1727 38.0
# 5.2 1745 36.0
```